# ffmpeg: "Input/output error" Read gif from named pipe?

Tags: ffmpeg, pipe, gif, mkfifo

I've been trying to debug this for hours now, and cannot seem to understand why it doesn't work.

I want to overlay a png onto all frames of a gif, and since writing all the files to disk is slow, i wanted to use pipes.

I created a named pipe using `mkfifo imgstream1` and then launch ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -report -hide_banner -v 9 -loglevel 99 -y -f gif -i imgstream1 out1.gif
```

(This isn't actually useful as it just spits out the same gif again but it's simpler for debugging)

After ffmpeg launches it waits for data from the pipe, so i write an actual gif file to the pipe using this kotlin code

```kotlin
val backgroundFifo = File("imgstream1")
val inputOne = File("background.gif").readBytes()
println("background.gif -> ${inputOne.size} bytes")
val output = backgroundFifo.outputStream()
output.write(inputOne)
output.flush()
output.close()
```

It prints: `background.gif -> 7233247 bytes`

Now ffmpeg should read the bytes and spit out a gif, but it always seems to fail doing so.

```
Opening an input file: imgstream1.
[gif @ 0x7714180] Opening 'imgstream1' for reading
[file @ 0x7714980] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto,data'
[AVIOContext @ 0x7724dc0] Statistics: 7233247 bytes read, 0 seeks
imgstream1: Input/output error
```

Sadly this does not give any further information, i'm already on the highest log level...

I've tried multiple things:

- `-f image2pipe` -> Works, but only loads the first 2 frames of the gif
- Renaming the pipe to `imgstream1.gif` so ffmpeg thinks it's a gif file, no change.
- Different ffmpeg versions
- Using the actual gif as an ffmpeg input works

At this point i have no idea what the problem might be, as ffmpeg seems to load all bytes.
It's worth noting that doing `cat imgstream1 > file.gif` produces the desired gif.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: should be `-i -` not `-i imgstream1`

Comment: @kesh `-i -` is for stdin pipes, `imgstream1` is an actual "file" in that directory that's created by `mkfifo`

Comment: Ok my bad. (learning something new everyday.) btw, what's your FFmpeg version? (I searched for "Input/output error" in the FFmpeg repo and came out empty. If it is an older release, maybe try a current release?)

Comment: Can you run `ffmpeg` inside of `strace` to see exactly which syscall is failing with `EIO (Input/output error)`?

Comment: @kesh I've tried both the latest stable version 4.2.7 and the current git master branch

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica This is the result https://hastebin.de/avizutobuw.txt

Comment: Seems like ffmpeg is using `lseek()`, which is obviously not working on pipes, so it's expecting a file... Don't know why it needs to seek though

Comment: That was what I was wondering as it is the same reason MP4 format cannot be piped and that's why `image2pipe` demuxer exists. Too bad it doesn't work with animated gifs. Are you retrieving gif over http? If so, have you tried to use the url as the input to ffmpeg?